# Youtube embedded video does not work on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, youtube

For months I've been noticing embedded youtube videos appear white on any other page, now I found out that I can watch those videos by inspecting the page and putting `-nocookie` at the hostname of the iframe src, i.e. `https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/(VIDEO_ID)`.
I want to know why this happen and how to fix it, my first thought was to make an userscript to change it in every page.

**EDIT:** It works fine on Edge and Firefox but not on Chrome, even though my settings for cookies are enabled.

**SOLUTION:** The problem was that my userscript on Tampermonkey extension (which was supposed to affect the youtube page) was affecting every page with an embedded video, from now on I can figure it out what part of the code was doing that but for now it's turned off.

Thanks to @JasonB for the suggestion about extensions.

Comment: Try toggling   Settings > Advanced > Use hardware acceleration when available

Comment: Also what extensions are installed?

Comment: @JasonB It was my fault, I explained better on the post.

Comment: Glad you found it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This -nocookie url came out almost a decade ago when cookies were still often turned off. This codepen shows that the standard youtube embed code works just fine on a simple site.

```
<iframe width="400" height="300" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Ht5RZpzPqw" frameborder="0" 
gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/baqdGz

Are there any details about your domain or a link to a broken embedded video on your site that might help us better troubleshoot your issue?

---

The thumbnail worked just fine, I left it open for 5 minutes and then played the video, and that is all functional. Looks like there's one js error related to the codepen setup - not what you're experiencing.

[image: Youtube embed on codepen]

Comment: Actually it's not only on my domain it's on every domain, and your codepen makes the thumbnail pop and then gone. Sorry I haven't responded sooner.

Comment: I've changed the title, aparently that only happens on Chrome, I still want to fix it.

Comment: Okay - Well the pop and gone is a good clue - we hope. My gut says it might be a browser setting - and now I see the Chrome comment in the post.

Comment: I had a GPU acceleration issue breaking video playback for me in c

Comment: hrome and I had tried lot's of stuff that did nothing to help before I found that. I'm looking for that setting now.