# Embed youtube videos in web getting `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, youtube-api, embed

```js
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}

// 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
//    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
//    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
var done = false;

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
    setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
    done = true;
  }
}

function stopVideo() {
  player.stopVideo();
}
```

```html
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div id="player"></div>
```

Embed youtube videos in web getting `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`. I copied the code from the youtube developer documentation [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Requirements). But I dont know why I get error. But I saw this demo [link](https://codepen.io/briangelhaus/pen/meeLRO) which is playing and I dont understand why. Also saw this SO question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47998362/youtube-embedded-video-does-not-work-on-chrome) which has a demo in [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/baqdGz) which also is not working.

Can any point me to where should I go?

Answer (score 0):

You have enclosed you code between opening and closing "script" brackets as shown below correct? No errors found. It should work...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = 
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, 
firstScriptTag);
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
height: '270',
width: '480',
videoId: 'nM82jzoJfjA',
events: {
'onReady': onPlayerReady,
'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
}
});
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
event.target.playVideo();
}
var done = false;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done)
{
setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
done = true;
}
}
function stopVideo() {
player.stopVideo();
}
</script>
<div id="player"></div>
```